# How to check in PowerShell if the script was run in background (e.g. Windows Task Scheduler) or in user session

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

How to check in PowerShell if the script was run in background (e.g. via Windows Task Scheduler) or in user session

Comment: In Windows Vista and above, system service and batch processes execute in session 0. In PowerShell, I suppose you could check either `(Get-Process -id $pid).SessionId` or `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().SessionId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the script (When the script is running) you can use $host.name

```
if ($host.name -match 'ise') {"Do not send mail.."}
if ($host.name -match 'console') {Send-mail...}
```